# Fancy animation using JavaScript/CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, flash

I wonder if fancy animations such as [this](http://visibletweets.com/#query=stackoverflow&animation=1) can easily be done using JavaScript and CSS. In particular, I would like to reproduce the "wind of letters" effect.

Comment: Why the downvote? Pretty interesting question, while it's not an in-depth explanation, the example site is something that's worth to be converted into JS/CSS (only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that with the use of [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could do most of the animations. I am not sure about the text blur and the 3D rotation may not be as nice.

I think though that the biggest problem would be trying to get the font animations to be as smooth as they are in flash. You would have to have each character as a separate element and perform a good few calculations when animating the text from one paragraph to the next. I would say any first attempt would leave you with pretty heavy lag, and I am not really sure how well it could be optimised to increase performance.

So in short, yes you could do this with JQuery, but more than likely you will not end up with the same smooth quality at the end.

To answer your question directly, I do not think that this would be an easy task.

Comment: That is not an easy task, but not impossible either. Dunno if jQuery is the answer, my bet would be that CSS3 3D transforms would be faster.. With JS of course, to sum it all up.

Comment: @Tom: I agree, it is certainly possible